# MissingMethodException in retrieving passed data through model attribute when rendering template gsp

Tags: java, grails, netbeans, gsp

I just recently started a **Grails project in Netbeans**. At some point, I need to pass parameters when rendering templates. I've searched here in stackoverflow on how to do that and the result is this code:

```
<g:render template="/omm/placeOrders/buySellOrders/details/accountDetails" model="[show_sub_fieldset:'false']" />
```

And on that `_accountDetails.gsp` file, to fetch that passed value on the model attribute, I used this `code` on the first line:

```
<%
  SHOW_SUB_FIELDSET = (${show_sub_fieldset} == true || ${show_sub_fieldset} == 'true');
%>
```

But I cannot retrieve the passed `show_sub_fieldset` variable, and instead, receive an **error**:

```
URI : /OMM-Revised/placeOrders/buySellOrders
Class : groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message : No signature of method:
  C__Users_Gideon_Bardelas_Documents_NetBeansProjects_OMM_Revised_grails_app_views_omm_placeOrders_buySellOrders_details__accountDetails_gsp.$() is applicable for argument types:
    (C__Users_Gideon_Bardelas_Documents_NetBeansProjects_OMM_Revised_grails_app_views_omm_placeOrders_buySellOrders_details__accountDetails_gsp$_run_closure1) values:
    [C__Users_Gideon_Bardelas_Documents_NetBeansProjects_OMM_Revised_grails_app_views_omm_placeOrders_buySellOrders_details__accountDetails_gsp$_run_closure1@62b49424]
  Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
```

Where did I go wrong? Do I need to configure some pages first? Does it have to do with Controllers? Thanks.

Comment: You have a simple typo where you shouldn't be using `${}` around your variables when you are doing your compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems removing `${}` from `${show_sub_fieldset}` works. Is it the proper solution, though?